# ActiveRecord: Update a record if exists else create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Trying to implement an create if not exists else update record in Active Record.

**Currently using:**

```
@student = Student.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first

if @student
    Student.destroy_all(:user_id => current_user.id)
end

Student = Student.new(:user_id => current_user.id, :department => 1
)
Student.save!
```

What would be the correct way of updating the record if it exists or else create it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may be looking for `first_or_create` or something similar:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17/active_record_querying.html#first_or_create

Comment: first_or_create does not update the record, so it doesn't make code any nicer.

Comment: But it *does* return the found or created record, so you can chain an `update` call onto it. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25497490/1157242) on this page.

Comment: This causes problems with validations on create and causes 2 separate db transactions.  The answer from @Zorayr is preferable as it respects validations.

Comment: That's true. To get through validations, I think you can use `first_or_initialize` in exactly the same way as `first_or_create`; but you *must* call `save` or `update` on the result for it to be persisted.

Comment: @rune-schjellerup-philosof but you can update it after that `.first_or_create(user_id: current_user.id, department: 1).update(department: 1)`

Answer (score 83):

In Rails 4

```
Student.
  find_or_initialize_by(:user_id => current_user.id).
  update_attributes!(:department => 1)
```

Comment: `find_or_initialize_by` + `update_attributes!` will do the trick

Comment: The return value from `update_attributes!` is a boolean and not the actual record. You can use `Student.find_or_initialize_by(...).tap { |e| e.update!(...) }`

Comment: There's a couple of problems - first, you've got no way to "only set values on create", and second, it looks at table columns rather than model methods. For example, `User.where(email: email).find_or_initialize_by(password: password)` would give you an error of `columns users.password does not exist` (assuming you're sensible and not storing plain passwords in the database).

Comment: Nice solution. In Rails 4, I would only change `.update_attributes` to `.update`. It's the idiomatic way of doing it and the source code reveal it's the same as .update_attributes! (it will simply assign the attributes and call `.save` ... check https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update and https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes).

Comment: Keep in mind that `find_or_initialize_by` may not trigger any validation

Answer (score 15):

`::first_or_create` (available since v3.2.1) does what it says on the box.

```
Model.where(find: 'find_value').
  first_or_create(create: 'create_value')

# If a record with {find: 'find_value'} already exists:
before #=> #<Model id: 1, find: "find_value", create: nil>
after  #=> #<Model id: 1, find: "find_value", create: nil>

# Otherwise:
before #=> nil
after  #=> #<Model id: 2, find: "find_value", create: "create_value">
```

If you *also want it to update* an already-existing record, try:

```
Model.where(find: 'find_value').
  first_or_create(create: 'create_value').
  update(update: 'update_value')

# If one already exists:
before #=> #<Model id: 1, find: "find_value", create: nil, update: nil>
after  #=> #<Model id: 1, find: "find_value", create: nil, update: "update_value">

# If it already matches, no UPDATE statement will be run:
before #=> #<Model id: 1, find: "find_value", create: nil, update: "update_value">
after  #=> #<Model id: 1, find: "find_value", create: nil, update: "update_value">

# Otherwise:
before #=> nil
after  #=> #<Model id: 2, find: "find_value", create: 'create_value', update: "update_value">
```

EDIT 2016-03-08: As per [Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142098/doug)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599113/activerecord-update-a-record-if-exists-else-create/25497490#comment56227983_14599178), if your validations fail between the `#create` and `#update` calls, or you want to minimise database calls, you can use `::first_or_initialize` instead, to avoid persisting the record on the first call. However, you **must** make sure you call `#save` or `#update` afterwards in order to persist the record (and I'm not sure if `#update` works on records that haven't been persisted yet):

```
Model.validates :update, presence: true # The create call would fail this

Model.where(find: 'find_value').
  first_or_initialize(create: 'create_value'). # doesn't call validations
  update(update: 'update_value')
```

(NB. There *is* a method called `#create_or_update`, but don't be fooled by any [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/create_or_update) you may find on Google; that's just a private method used by `#save`.)

Answer (score 7):

```
@student = Student.where(user_id: current_user.id).first
@student ||= Student.new(user_id: current_user.id)
@student.department_id = 1
@student.save
```

This is prettier if you have an association between a user and a student.  Something along the lines of

```
@student = current_user.student || current_user.build_student
@student.department_id = 1
@student.save
```

EDIT:

You can also use http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#first_or_create as answered by sevenseacat but you still have to deal with different scenarios like update a student's department id.

UPDATE:

You can use [`find_or_create_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by)

```
@student = Student.find_or_create_by(user_id: current_user.id) do |student|
  student.department_id = 1
end
```

Answer (score 7):

In Rails 5

```
Student.
  find_or_initialize_by(:user_id => current_user.id).
  update(:department => 1)
```

(with all credit taken from @Zorayr answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think the cleanest way to do this is:

```
Student.where(user_id: id).first_or_create(age: 16).update_attribute(:age, 16)
```

Answer (score -4):

It's **find_or_create_by** not **first_or_create**.
Ex: 
Client.find_or_create_by(first_name: 'Andy')

Comment: [first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) does exist, (even a year ago), I'm not sure what you were trying to say with this answer, but it sounds like it was meant as a comment on another post.

Comment: The two also work slightly differently. `Model.where(find: 'find_value').first_or_create(create: 'create_value')` is equivalent to `Model.find_or_create_by(find: 'find_value') { |r| r.create = 'create_value' }`.